# Difference between derived attribute and regular attribute

Tags: ios, core-data

I have been going through the apple documentation where they have used the derived property to store the normalized version of their regular text. So, for example, if the regular text is "Hello" (with some special character), then the normalized text is derived as "hello".

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DerivedProperty/Listings/DerivedProperty_APLDocument_m.html

However, when I looked at their managed object model, then I see that the derived property is also entered as an attribute of the entity in question. So, the entity has both the regular text as well as the derived text as attributes. :-

1. So, what exactly is the difference between derived attribute and regular
   attribute if we are storing both in the persistent store and both
   can be indexed in core data ?
2. Can derived attribute be synced through icloud ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property can be derived whether you store it persistently or not. Whether you choose to store it persistently or transiently depends on what you're going to do with it. For example, if you wanted to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` which was sorted on the attribute then it needs to be persistent. If the FRC was just going to be grouped by the attribute (section name key path) then it could just be transient.

Anything stored persistently would be synced (but anything derived can also be recalculated later).

Comment: Also, if I want to search on a derived property(which is a string and I will not be doing an exact match), then I assume that that derived property should be indexed. However, for indexing, the derived property should be persistent, right ?

Comment: Yes, basically anything that you want to run in a fetch request on the store needs to be persistent.